# URL Validation REGEX - URL valid with http://, www. , https://www. , http://www. only

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want an regular expression which excepts above url and the words can be in capital letters also.
I am not getting any regular expression. This code is not working properly.

```
var url="www.google";
var Regex=/^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?(www.)?\w+(\.\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})\/?$/;
if(Regex.test(url))
{
      alert("true");
}
else
{
alert("false");
}
```

Comment: Yeah!! I am using javascript where I had to pass the regex expression and check whether it is true or not. Can you tell the regex of this which can validate the urls which I wanted to validate

Comment: I had put the code but It is not working properly. Can you help me out in changing this code

Answer (score 1):

I have kept the expression oversimplified.

```
/^(https?\:\/\/www\.)?(www.)?\w+(\.\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})\/?$/i
```

Comment: Hey it is working but It is not working for the cases like google.com or GOOGLE.COM  Can you add the expression so that it can run for this also for capital letters or without any initials

Comment: I hope this will help you. But, I will highly recommend you to revise regex again. Your regex contains a lot of mistakes. And This regEx will also match urls of type http//google.com. I think you wanted this but, forgot to include in the question. And please accept the answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: I wanted that it except google.com or yahoo.com which are without http or www . And one thing more it is also excepting case like www.google.gfbuksgbusg which is not a proper case it must have atmost 4 characters after last dot. Can you please correct. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: It was already matching with google.com & yahoo.com... I have fixed it now to include the validation rules you wanted. I hope this will help you know

Comment: one thing more if we have put https:// or http:// then it is necessary that www. will come it is mandatory can you just correct once more last time.

Comment: /^(http\:\/\/www.|https\:\/\/www.|www.)?(www.)?\w+(\.\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})\/?$/    
In this can you just tell how to correct this case hwww or wwcdsw case

Comment: I didn't get what are you asking... And I guess my current answer satisfies your constraints..

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a special meta chracter in regex which matches any character. You need to escape it to match a literal `.`

```
^(https?:\/\/(www\.)|(www\.))?\w+(\.\w{2,4})\/?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iC8wX6/7)

Add `i` modifier to make your regex to do a case insensitive match.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66818/discussion-on-answer-by-avinash-raj-url-validation-regex-url-valid-with-http).